# WorkflowSubscriptionCollection always returning empty

Tags: office-365, designer-workflow, jsom

I am trying get all **workflow subscriptions** on list using JSOM, But collection is always returning empty. I have associated reusable workflow on content type within list.

Below is my code:

```
              function getWFSubs(){
                    var listGuid = "A6420422-4D86-424C-A435-9F28530104E8";     
                    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    var web = context.get_web();
                    context.load(web);
                    var sMgr = new SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
                    context.load(sMgr);
                    var sservice = sMgr.getWorkflowSubscriptionService();
                    context.load(sservice);
                    var ssubs = sservice.enumerateSubscriptionsByList(listGuid);
                    context.load(ssubs);
                    context.executeQueryAsync(
                       function(){
                           console.log(ssubs.get_count());
                           var e = ssubs.getEnumerator();                   
                           while(e.moveNext())
                           {
                               var c =  e.get_current();
                               console.log("Name :" + c.get_name() + " sID: " + c.get_id());
                           };

                       },
                       function(){ alert("error")});
                }
```

console.log(ssubs.get_count()); displaying 0. Whats wrong with my code?

Environment: **Office365**